# Update the table using stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table and I have 50 columns in it. From my code behind at first I am inserting 10 values using a stored procedure, after that in second page based on userid I want to update other 40 columns. So I am updating the table and the userid column of the table is an identity column which is auto incremented so how to get the user id for update stored procedure?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_update
     (@FormFiledBy varchar(50), @MaritalStatus varchar(50),
      @Height varchar(50), @Religion varchar(50), @Caste varchar(100),
      @MotherTongue varchar(50), @Education varchar(100),
      @Occupation varchar(50), @CountryofResidence varchar(50), 
      @EducationDetails varchar(100), @AnnualIncome varchar(50), 
      @CountryOfBirth varchar(50), @BirthPlace varchar(50), 
      @TimeOfBirth nchar(10), @StarSign varchar(100),
      @Gothram varchar(50), @Rassi varchar(50), @HavinChildren varchar(10),
      @PhysicalStatus varchar (100)
     )
AS
BEGIN      
    UPDATE Profile_Master
    SET FormFiledBy = @FormFiledBy,
        MaritalStatus = @MaritalStatus,
        Height = @Height,
        physicalStatus = @physicalStatus,
        Religion = @Religion,
        Caste = @Caste,
        MotherTongue = @MotherTongue,
        Education = @Education,
        Occupation = @Occupation,
        CountryofResidence = @CountryofResidence,
        EducationDetails = @EducationDetails,
        AnnualIncome = @AnnualIncome,
        CountryOfBirth = @CountryOfBirth,
        BirthPlace = @BirthPlace,
        TimeOfBirth = @TimeOfBirth,
        StarSign = @StarSign,
        Gothram = @Gothram,
        Rassi = @Rassi,
        HavinChildren = @HavinChildren,
        PhysicalStatus = @PhysicalStatus
    WHERE 
        ????
END
```

Comment: Is there some other unique key you could go by, besides the id column?  For example, columns X-Y-and-Z constitute a unique key so you could just go by that instead of the userid column?

Comment: Yes the emailid column has a unique key....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your initial procedure, when you insert the data, you should retrieve and return the userid value in an OUTPUT parameter so that you can then supply it to your update procedure.

You can use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` for this fairly easily.

---

As requested, some sample code (simplified, but you should see the pattern):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE add_row @data1 varchar(20), @data2 varchar(20), @id int OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Table (Data1, Data2) VALUES (@data1, @data2)

    SELECT @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
END
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE update_row @id int, @data3 varchar(20), @data4 varchar(20)
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE Table SET Data3 = @data3, Data4 = @data4
    WHERE Id = @id
END
GO
```

Comment: can you please show me some code for this?? and how to supply the parameter for the update procedure?

Comment: Even in my insert procedure i am not inserting userid as it is identity column so it is auto incremented so how to set scope_identity for user id column??

Comment: @Chandrasekhar -- Added an example of usage for you.

Comment: @mwigdahl-- but  when i insert the record at first page i am getting an exception like-- Procedure or function 'Insertreg' expects parameter '@id', which was not supplied.

Comment: @Chandrasekhar -- then you are going to need to modify the invocation of the insert procedure so that it provides the additional parameter.  Just because it's an `OUTPUT` parameter doesn't mean you don't need to provide it in the call.  The signature of the procedure always needs to match the invocation.

Comment: you mean in the code behind? can you tell me what exactly invocation means?

Comment: Invocation means calling the stored procedure.  So if you call the procedure, you need to make sure that the code that calls it provides all the parameters the procedure takes, including any output parameters.  So yes, if your code behind is actually what calls the stored procedure, you'll need to modify it to provide all the parameters the procedure needs.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need update your primary key, but you must pass UserId as parameter of your stored procedure.

```
Update Profile_Master
Set ....
Where UserId = @UserId --your parameter
```

Nota : yuo must ensure that your primary key is just UserId

Answer (score 0):

You just have to pass `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` from fist Stored Procedure as below:

```
@Id int OUTPUT,

---
SET @Id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

And in the second Stored Procedure Apply the `Id` as an argument an `Update` the record based on that.

```
@Id VARCHAR(15)
Update Profile_Master
set ....
........
where UserId = @Id
```

Comment: Even in my insert procedure i am not inserting userid as it is identity column so it is auto incremented so how to set scope_identity for user id column??

Comment: You don't have to set `scope_identity` explicitly..it will be automatically assigned by the `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` method...@Chandrasekhar